# ESD Capacitor Calculation, 330Ohm Series Resistor and ESD Clamp Voltage

Tags: voltage, capacitor, high-voltage, esd, static

I have a input power filter circuit.

It has ESD Protection capacitors which help to protect the downstream circuit from ESD Pulses.

[image]

**ESD Capacitors Specifications :**

C0001, C0002, C0003, C0004 = 47nF, 100V, 10%, 0805

**My ESD Pulse Specifications :**

Contact Discharge : +/-4kV & 150pF / 330Ohms

Contact Discharge : +/-8kV & 150pF / 330Ohms

Air Discharge : +/-15kV & 150pF / 330Ohms

**My ESD Calculation:**

For example, I take the +/-8kV & 150pF spec

Consider the -8kV pulse

Q=CV ;

8kV * 150pF = 1200nC

This Charge will then get to the input ESD Capacitors :

V=Q/C;

1200nC / 23.5nF = 51.06V ----- This is less than 200V (both capacitors are connected in series)

**Required Capacitance:**

[image]

=((8000V*150pF)/40V)-150pF = 29.85nF  ---- Assume my Clamp voltage is 40V at the cathode of D0002

Therefore, the voltage ratings of the capacitors are satisfied. But the required capacitance is very much higher than 23.5nF which I have.

My questions :

1. Are my calculations of the Required Capacitance section correct? If they are correct, my circuit will fail at -8kV pulse right? What to do in this scenario?
2. I have never included the 330ohm series resistance in my theroretical calculations. Should I include the 330ohm series resistor in my calculations? If so, where?
3. On what should should I set my ESD Clamp voltage? In this case, I have set it to 40V since the absolute maximum ratings of the components present in the downstream is 40V? Is it Ok ? Or on what basis should I select my ESD Clamp voltage?

Comment: Where did the 330 pF suddenly come from in your calculations? It should be 150 pF hence, the peak voltage from an 8 kV discharge will be 51.06 volts.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. The spec is 330pF and not 150pF. I changed it

Comment: Then shouldn't the series resistor be 2 kohm for this type of model? Maybe you are working to a spec I haven't used so, to make things clear, please state the specification.

Comment: Ok. Lets not focus on the spec more. Can you just help me with my questions with the my mentioned spec/

Comment: I'm asking because I mistrust your model that uses 330 pF and 330 ohm. The only model I've ever seen/used that uses 330 pF has the series resistor at 2 kohm and that makes a difference for question 3.

Comment: Yes I have mixed the specification. Please excuse me and bear with me for that. There is no model and I am not concerned with the simulations. Just want to understand the theoretical answers regard to my questions.

Comment: Or else we can use the 150pF and 330 ohms instead of 330pF and 330ohms model.

Comment: Yes, modified the spec to 150pF and 330Ohms

Comment: Haven't you already answered your first question by correcting the question? For Q2 I mentioned on an earlier question that your capacitors will still receive the same charge irrespective of the resistor value. As for the surge protection device (SPD), I recommend using a simulator and modelling the SPD when connected with 47 nF capacitors and receiving a pulse from the 150 pF + 330 ohm.

Comment: What about the third question